# How to fix "`require_relative': cannot load such file" cannot load - Ruby

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

Tried to solve this on my own and so far no luck...

Error below:

```
1: from bin/run:3:in `<main>'
bin/run:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/jason/Development/code/First Project/bin/bin/environment.rb (LoadError)
```

What's in my bin folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative './bin/environment.rb'

CLI.new.call
```

In my config folder:

```
require 'pry'
require 'httparty'

require_relative "./lib/api.rb"
require_relative "./lib/cli.rb"
require_relative "./lib/pokemon.rb"
```

Project Directory:

```
-->Firstproject
 ->bin
   -run
->config
   -environment.rb
 ->lib
   -api.rb
   -cli.rb
   -pokemon.rb
-gitignore
-Gemfile
-README.md
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to adjust the path to correctly reference your `environment.rb` source file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative '../config/environment.rb'

CLI.new.call
```

If you look closely where your `environment.rb` file lives, it is in the `project_dir/config/environment.rb` but your `bin/run` you are attempting to locate the file at `./bin/environment.rb` which doesn't exist according to your Project Directory layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your environment.rb file lives in config folder, not in lib. So change it to

> require_relative './config/environment.rb'